# Moving and Relocating HTML elements

Tags: dojo

The following code works fine.But when the drop-down list is displayed it should not override the button elements named get value and get displayed value below it..instead the buttons should movedown when the dropdown is displayed and after a particular item is selected the button shoud come to the original position.

```
<html >
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script src='dojo/dojo.js'></script>
    <script>
require([
    "dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Memory, FilteringSelect){
    var stateStore = new Memory({
        data: [
            {name:"Alabama", id:"AL"},
            {name:"Alaska", id:"AK"},
            {name:"American Samoa", id:"AS"},
            {name:"Arizona", id:"AZ"},
            {name:"Arkansas", id:"AR"},
            {name:"Armed Forces Europe", id:"AE"},
            {name:"Armed Forces Pacific", id:"AP"},
            {name:"Armed Forces the Americas", id:"AA"},
            {name:"California", id:"CA"},
            {name:"Colorado", id:"CO"},
            {name:"Connecticut", id:"CT"},
            {name:"Delaware", id:"DE"}
        ]
    });

   var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
        id: "stateSelect",
        name: "state",
        value: "CA",
        store: stateStore,
        searchAttr: "name"
    }, "stateSelect");
    var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
        id: "stateSelect1",
        name: "state",
        value: "CA",
        store: stateStore,
        searchAttr: "name"
    }, "stateSelect1");
});
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <input id="stateSelect"><br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
     <input id="stateSelect1">
      <input id="stateSelect">
<p>
    <button onclick="alert(dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('value'))">Get value</button>
    <button onclick="alert(dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('displayedValue'))">Get displayed value</button>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "should not override the button elements" because it certainly should. The drop down menu is supposed to be an overlay, it's not part of the page. Whether or not you want it to be part of the page is different.

You cannot easily do this with the filtering select. The filtering select appends the div it uses to hold options, to the bottom of the page. You cannot show it in the normal flow of the page. You will have to create a custom widget that appends its options inside a container directly below the select input.

But I don't know what you are trying to solve by doing this. My advice would be to leave it as is unless you have a really good reason to change it. The drop down menu is a pretty well-ingrained component of GUIs, so changing the behavior of it is not recommended.

Edit:
If you want to limit the height of the drop-down. Set the "maxHeight" of the filteringSelect.

```
 var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
    id: "stateSelect",
    name: "state",
    value: "CA",
    store: stateStore,
    searchAttr: "name",
    maxHeight: 40
}, "stateSelect");
```

Here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/8sh24/

Comment: OK Matt,Can a scrollbar be added to the filtering select

Comment: @user2956454, I have edited my answer to limit the size of the dropdown. A scrollbar will automatically be added if needed.